# Compiling and executing a C file in gvim on windows 7

Tags: gcc, vim

I wrote this simple program in gvim: 'myFile.c'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 9;
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a + b);
    return 0;
}
```

In gvim the following instruction
`:!gcc -o myFile.exe % && myFile.exe`

errors to:

gcc: error: myFile.c: No such file or directory.

gcc: fatal error: no input files.

compilation terminated.

If I change the percent sign which doesn't expand correctly:

`:!gcc -o myFile.exe c:\users\myName\desktop\folder\myFile.c && myFile.exe`

the program compiles and executes.

How to make the % expands to the path shown above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should change the directory to where your C file is. Otherwise, you're looking for `%:p` instead of just `%`.

BTW, why don't you use the quickfix mode? It'll let you display errors and warnings into the quickfix window, and if you use a properly configured version of gnumake (i.e. all versions but the version from mingw), you'll get `:make %<` for free -- you may have to change the directory before, or use something else than `%<`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. When I `:cd` in gvim I am in the current directory where my C file resides. I only want to understand why the `:!gcc % -o myFile.exe` does not see myFile.c

Comment: What do `:!pwd` or `:!ls` tell you? (it may be `:!dir`, I don't know pwd equivalent in pure msdos/windows world)

Comment: You rock. in fact: `:!dir` lists all the root directory \ .  When I do `:!dir` $home\..\folder` I can see it.  Moreover I understood that the `%` substitues the buffer in GVIM. The problem is in gvim and how it uses its built-in `cd`